# Execute diff.py from a python script and redirect the output to a file

Tags: python

I am very new to Python. I need to run diff.py(a python in built script) from my python script,to compare 2 files. I have used the system command in Perl before to do some stuff similar to this,but I cant seem to get it with python.
 I tried os.system and the subprocess module but no luck yet.
Any help will be much appreciated,
Thanks
Mohima C

Comment: Show us your code, we will try to show you bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the script `diff.py` simply calls a single function from the [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) module, it's much easier and more flexible to call this function yourself.  What function exactly you'd need to call [depends on the command line options you would pass to `diff.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/22db03646d9b/Tools/scripts/diff.py#l38).

In conclusion, don't call a subprocess for this.

Comment: I want to compare contents of two files and save the output in a text file.

Comment: Thanks , I called the context_diff function from the difflib module and it works for my requirement